# В чём отличая между шифрованиями AesManaged и Rijndael?

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём разница между AesManaged и Rijndael  это же по сути одно и тоже?

Хочу попробовать зашифровать файл при помощи Aes256 но пока полного примера не нашёл ( буду искать ).

Вообще очень много вопросов будет по поводу шифрования)) надеюсь мне помогут тут ответят на них

Мне нужно будет шифровать очень много файлов разного размера, даже большого размера, все рекомендуют алгоритм AES 256 -  Его ли нужно использовать для таких целей ?

Answer (score 1):

Разницы никакой. Если посмотреть исходники, то видно, что `AesManaged` по сути создает экземпляр `RinjaelManaged` и вызывает его методы.

Можете шифровать любым `AES` (128, 192, 256 бит), он создан для таких целей. Примеров шифрования огромное количество.

Comment: Если будут другие вопросы, лучше задавайте их отдельно.